# How to make menu bar shadow bigger when scroll?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show little shadow in menu bar but when some some scroll the shadow will be bigger yes I make it's position fixed. Please answer with javascript code, I don't want to add jquery. Thank you.

**JS**

```
function navscroll()
{
navscroll=document.getElementById("menu");
if(navscroll => 0){
    navscroll.style['mox-box-shadow']="0 0 1px 1px #aaa";
}
else {
    navscroll.style['mox-box-shadow']="1px 1px 2px 2px #aaa";
}
}
```

**HTML**
    `<div id="menu" onscroll="navscroll()">`

Comment: http://kizu.ru/en/fun/shadowscroll/

Comment: may be you need to try `moz-box-shadow` instead of `mox-box-shadow`?

Comment: yes I have add the moz and webkit too but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

i did a working fiddle there you go

http://jsfiddle.net/H9kVL/

```
window.addEventListener('mousewheel',function(){
document.getElementById('shadow').style['box-shadow'] = '3px 3px 3px #000';
})
```

change the id and it should work